# Angular lazy loading duplicate modules

Tags: angular

I am trying to integrate lazy loading into my Angular application.

I have 4 modules. Each module is lazy loaded.

- FirstPageWithTitleModule
- SecondPageWithTileModule
- ThirdPageWithTitleModule
- RandomModule

The first 3 modules are importing my custom TitleModule.

My question: what happens with the TitleModule if all routes are lazyLoaded? Will it be generated 3 times and add its size to the lazyLoadedModule? Or will it be generated only 1 time with a single file size and used across all three modules?

Comment: What will the build tell me?

Comment: What files get created, and what is in the files. Seems like that should answer your questions.

Comment: I believe they will land in bundle multiple times. Primarily if you're aware of constant usage of `TitleModule`, then why don't you think of loading it inside `CoreModule`/`ShareModule` itself.

Comment: So rather split into 2modules -- 1module without the Pge title and 1 Module with 3modules inside that share the titleModule?

Comment: I do not see details here. If all these first three modules are lazy loaded, why are you importing them inside Title module ?

Module means - collect all necessary services, components, pipes and other angular building block together. After that, you attach the module to the specific route.

Here comes a question, if all these three modules are attached to the route, then why are you importing that inside a TitleModule ?

Answer (score 4):

Here's a working project of this example: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xzxmzp?embed=1&file=src/app/TitleModule/title-module.ts).

I'm answering those two questions:

**1. How many times `TitleModule`(title.module.ts) will appear in the bundles?**

Answer: **1**.

Since `TitleModule` is imported in multiple [dependency graph](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/dependency-graph/)s,

(one for each LazyLoaded module. e.g: `loadChildren: () => import('app/first-page-with-title-module.module').then(m =>m.FirstPageWithTitleModule)` )

Webpack is smart enough to detect those multiple references and he'll create a separate chunk for the shared modules(files). (Angular runs as a plugin inside webpack)

Here is a [small example from webpack documentation](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/#defaults-example-2) that correlates with this scenario.

**In the demo**: You can see in the console that
title-module.ts is parsed by webpack 1 time. Since webpack pushed the module(file) only once to the bundle, it only needs to read it once, and then its on its cache.

**2. How many times `TitleModule` will be instantiate?**

Answer: **3**

Each `loadChildren` callback eventually ends up [here in angular source code](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/d1ea1f4c7f3358b730b0d94e65b00bc28cae279c/packages/router/src/router_config_loader.ts#L41) and executes `factory.create(parentInjector)` which means a new NgModule is created as a child of the parent route.

So now we have 3 new lazy loaded modules:

- FirstPageWithTitleModule
- SecondPageWithTileModule
- ThirdPageWithTileModule

Each one creates `TitleModule` object when he tries to decipher the `import` array of its `NgModule` decorator. `TitleModule` object doesn't exists in the `parentInjector` and lazy modules do not share Modules, InjectionTokens(providers) unless they are in a shared ancestor injector.

**In the demo**: You can see in the console.log that
TitleModule is instantiate 3 times(each time you enter a route it'll instantiate - unless it was already created in this route) - max number of 3.